# automatically get a quit when running gdb in script

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to use gdb to debug a new process which is created by a script.
In the linux shell, I tried this:

```
ps -ef | grep -i [m]yprocess |  awk '{print "gdb -p "  $2}'  | sh
```

Every time，gdb got a ‘quit’ automatically then quit:

```
***0xf7788430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-105.i686 libgcc-4.8.3-10.i686
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.
    Inferior 1 [process 834] will be detached.
Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]***
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like the message is telling you to call `debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-105.i686 libgcc-4.8.3-10.i686`. Perhaps looking into `debuginfo-install` would help?

Comment: if the input by hand like "gdb -p myprocess_id",it could work. so that's not the direct reason i get an "quit"

Answer (score 1):

You can do just

```
gdb -p `pgrep myprocess`
```

I guess weird behavior is the consequence of STDIN not being a terminal but a pipe from `awk`.

Comment: thanks!    i tried sevral time then realized the problem might be with the pipe.  since export abc=$(pgrep 'myprocess') | gdb -p $abc still got an quit. so now i'm using the script instead of an one line command seprated by pipe